# Can I use Tensorflow in reactjs? (not react-native)

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I want to use deep learning or machine learning to do some calculations on my front-end.

But there are no react examples.

My original idea was use python with react. Tensorflow would run in back-end in Python, while the front-end would be using React and get the results from the Python back-end.

Then I saw that Tensorflow is also in Javascript. So it can be used directly on the website, right?

Can React then directly use Tensorflow?

Comment: Yes you can, however - React has nothing to do with Tensorflow js, React is just a UI library, Tensorflow is a Machine learning library. There's nothing stopping you from using both, and there's no need to have a "wrapper" like answer below suggests

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can install it NPM, it is at their documentation: https://js.tensorflow.org/setup/

`yarn add @tensorflow/tfjs` or `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs`

Then `import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, [TensorFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/) is designed for just this use case. You may need to find some React wrapper libraries or wrap it up yourself but it is completely possible.